# Updating Meteor hourly by importing json

Tags: javascript, json, meteor, telescope, kimono

I am trying to automatically update Meteor, to be more specific Meteor-based Telescope framework with json regularly, each hour. To be more specific, json will be generated by Kimono Labs. So  I am just trying to glue the two together.

Each hour when json is updated by Kimono, my Meteor/Telescope should import and tag the relevant updates and post them.

Please direct me refer me to some relevant sources. I apologize in advance if this is very newbie or poorly-articulated question!

Answer (score 1):

The [synced-cron package](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron) is an excellent way to build recurring processes such as this one. Assuming you GET a json object you should be able to quickly save all or parts of it as one or more mongo documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Telescope's own [`telescope:post-by-feed`](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/tree/master/packages/telescope-post-by-feed) package, which does exactly that but for RSS feeds.